# setblock spawner

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Why does the mob_spawner created using this command doesn't create any entity. How to correct the following command:

```
/setblock ~0 ~1 ~0 mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnCount:1,SpawnRange:3,maxNearbyEntities:3,Delay:2,MinSpawnDelay:250,MaxSpawnDelay:420,EntityId:Skeleton,SpawnData:{CustomName:"sh_shadow",SkeletonType:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:12,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999,ShowParticles:0b}],Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:10},{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:0.20},{Name:generic.attackDamage,Base:0},{Name:generic.followRange,Base:12},{Name:generic.knockbackResistance,Base:9}],HealF:10,Invulnerable:1,Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:minecraft:arrow}]}}
```

Comment: After reading your answer, are you saying that it did not spawn any mobs? Or are you getting an error when you execute this command?

Answer (score -2):

The place where I tested the mob spawner was too enlightened. (ongoing fustigation :x)

Comment: Do you mean that the light level was too high?